# Show that if $[e_a, e_b] = C^c_{ab}e_c$, $d\theta^a = -\frac12C^a_{bc}\theta^b\wedge \theta^c$

Tags: differential-geometry

I’m trying to show the second equation of the second answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/586896/commutators-and-coordinate-induced-basis-general-relativity) on Physics StackExchange:

> If $e_1,…,e_n$ is a frame, and $\theta^1,…,\theta^n$ is its dual frame, and the direct frame satisfies the commutation relations $$ [e_a,e_b]=C^c_{\ ab}e_c, $$ then it is easy to show that the dual frame satisfies the differential relations $$ \mathrm d\theta ^a=-\frac{1}{2}C^a_{\ bc}\theta^b\wedge\theta^c=-\sum_{b<c}C^a_{\ bc}\theta^b\wedge \theta^c. $$

How is this shown? Are these differential relations related to the ones in Chapter 2 Problem 4b) of Wald’s book “General Relativity”:

$$\frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial(Y^{\gamma*})_{\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} = C^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}(Y^{\alpha*})_{\mu}(Y^{\beta*})_{\nu}.$$

If not, how are these latter equations shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b<c$, we computing using the **In terms of invariant formula** from the [wiki page on exterior derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative),
\begin{align}
d\theta^a(e_b, e_c) &= e_b\theta^a(e_c) - e_c\theta^a(e_b)-\theta^a([e_b,e_c])\\
&= e_b\delta_c^a - e_c\delta^a_b-C_{bc}^d\theta^a(e_d)\\
&=-C_{bc}^a.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$d\theta^a = -\sum_{b<c}C_{bc}^a\theta^b\wedge \theta^c = -\frac{1}{2}C_{bc}^a\theta^b\wedge \theta^c,
$$
by the skew-symmetry of $C_{bc}$ and $\theta^b\wedge\theta^c$ in $b$ and $c$, where the last sum is over all $b$ and $c$.

Interpreting your second equation, you have to regard $Y^{\gamma*}$ to be the $\theta^\gamma$ in your above equation. Then we have
$$
d(Y^{\gamma*}) = -\frac 1 2 C_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma Y^{\alpha*}\wedge Y^{\beta*}.
$$
The new information is that we use the coordinates and write
$$
Y^{\gamma*}=(Y^{\gamma*})_\mu dx^\mu.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
d(Y^{\gamma*})&=\sum_{\nu<\mu} \Big(\frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\Big) dx^\nu\wedge dx^\mu\\
&=\frac 1 2 \Big(\frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\Big) dx^\nu\wedge dx^\mu\\
&=-\frac 1 2 \Big(\frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\Big) dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu,
\end{align}
where the second last line is again by skew-symmetries. The right hand side is
$$
 -\frac 1 2 C_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma Y^{\alpha*}\wedge Y^{\beta*} = -\frac 1 2 C_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma (Y^{\alpha*})_\mu(Y^{\beta*})_\nu dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu.
$$
Comparing the coefficients (and also because they are both skew-symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$), we get the desired
$$
\frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial (Y^{\gamma*})_\nu}{\partial x^\mu}=C_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma (Y^{\alpha*})_\mu(Y^{\beta*})_\nu.
$$

So basically we use $b<c$ and $\nu<\mu$ when we do concrete calculations, but we use the symmetry of the situation to make the indices general, with a $\frac 1 2$ introduced.