A coordinate free interpretation of Wald, "General Relativity", Chapter 2, Exercise 4b
Fix a (Lorentzian) manifold $ M $, and let $ Y_{(1)},\dots,Y_{(n)} $ be a frame field on $ M $. Denote with $ Y^{(1)},\dots,Y^{(n)} $ the dual coframe. R. Wald in its General Relativity ask in Exercise 4b to show that
$$
\frac{\partial Y_\mu^{(\gamma)}}{\partial x^\nu} - \frac{\partial Y_\nu^{(\gamma)}}{\partial x^\mu} = \sum_{\alpha,\beta}C_{\alpha\beta}^{(\gamma)}Y_\mu^{(\alpha)}Y_\nu^{(\beta)}
$$
where by definition
$$
[Y_{(\alpha)},Y_{(\beta)}] = C_{\alpha\beta}^\sigma Y_{(\sigma)}
$$
for some scalars $ C_{\alpha\beta}^\sigma $.
I would like to provide a coordinate-free proof of this fact. I already recognized the LHS as the coordinates of the exterior derivative of $ Y^{(\gamma)} $ with respect to a fixed coordinate frame induced by the local coordinates $ x^1,\dots,x^n $, and I only need to show that
$$
\mathrm d Y^{(\gamma)} = \dots
$$
But... what $ 2 $-formon $ M $ has for coordinates
$$
\sum_{\alpha,\beta}C_{\alpha\beta}^{(\gamma)}Y_\mu^{(\alpha)}Y_\nu^{(\beta)}
$$
with respect to the same elementary basis $ \mathrm dx^\mu\wedge \mathrm dx^\nu $?

$Y^{(\gamma)}$ is a $1$-form, so its exterior derivative is a $2$-form, and $\{Y^{(i)}\wedge Y^{(j)}\,:\, 1\leq i<j\leq n\}$ forms a basis for $2$-forms, so we can express the former as a linear combination of the latter. The point of the exercise is that these coefficients also appear in the Lie bracket.
This is essentially leading you to the abstract definition of the exterior derivative of a $1$-form: $(d\omega)(X,Y)=L_X\left(\omega(Y)\right)-L_Y\left(\omega(X)\right)-\omega([X,Y])$.
(And recall that for a function $f$, we have $L_Xf:= (df)(X):= Xf$).

Yup, I realized after posting that this is basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872369/1141134.
